# two string values for constructor using castle windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am currently trying this:

```
var dependencies = new Dependency[2];
dependencies[0] = Dependency.OnValue("x", "xV");
dependencies[1] = Dependency.OnValue("y", "yV");
container.Register(
    Component.For<IBla>().ImplementedBy<BlaConcrete>().DependsOn(dependencies));
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. The exception is:

```
Could not resolve non-optional dependency
```

The simplified concrete looks like this:

```
public class Bla : IBla
{
    private readonly string _x;
    private readonly string _y;

    public Bla(string x, string y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }
]
```

Comment: What does "does not seem to work" mean?  Do you get an exception? (if so, where?) Do you get results you don't expect?

Comment: Add the entire exception; it tells you which dependency it couldn't resolve.  Also add the constructor of `BlaConcrete` to your question.

Comment: why do you want to close this. it is a valid question. if not please at least justify your vote for closure

Comment: People are voting to close it because until you added details (of which you could add more), it was a "this code doesn't work" question which [should be closed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/1698557).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something else in your code causing the issue because in an empty project this code works as expected:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
    var dependencies = new Dependency[2];
    dependencies[0] = Dependency.OnValue("x", "xV");
    dependencies[1] = Dependency.OnValue("y", "yV");
    container.Register(Component.For<IBla>().ImplementedBy<Bla>().DependsOn(dependencies));
    var bla = container.Resolve<IBla>();
}

public interface IBla 
{
}

public class Bla : IBla
{
    readonly string _x;
    readonly string _y;

    public Bla(string x, string y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }
}
```

Putting after breakpoint on the `Resolve` call shows that `bla` has `"xV"` and `"yV"` as values for its internal members.

*After you inspect the exception being thrown for more details (I promise there are more)*, I'd suggest removing parts of your application in pieces to see which has an effect on this.  Alternatively, start from an empty project like this and add pieces of your application that might affect this.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming that my orginal code works. I am an idiot the settings were not picked up form the web.config file in the integration test.